# How can I circumvent page view limits when scraping web data using Python?

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am using Python to scrape US postal code population data from http:/www.city-data.com, through this directory: http://www.city-data.com/zipDir.html. The specific pages I am trying to scrape are individual postal code pages with URLs like this: http://www.city-data.com/zips/01001.html. All of the individual zip code pages I need to access have this same URL Format, so my script simply does the following for postal_code in range:

1. Creates URL given postal code
2. Tries to get response from URL
3. If (2), Check the HTTP of that URL
4. If HTTP is 200, retrieves the HTML and scrapes the data into a list
5. If HTTP is not 200, pass and count error (not a valid postal code/URL)
6. If no response from URL because of error, pass that postal code and count error
7. At end of script, print counter variables and timestamp

The problem is that I run the script and it works fine for ~500 postal codes, then suddenly stops working and returns repeated timeout errors. My suspicion is that the site's server is limiting the page views coming from my IP address, preventing me from completing the amount of scraping that I need to do (all 100,000 potential postal codes).

My question is as follows: Is there a way to confuse the site's server, for example using a proxy of some kind, so that it will not limit my page views and I can scrape all of the data I need?

Thanks for the help! Here is the code:

```
##POSTAL CODE POPULATION SCRAPER##

import requests

import re

import datetime

def zip_population_scrape():

    """
    This script will scrape population data for postal codes in range 
    from city-data.com.
    """
    postal_code_data = [['zip','population']] #list for storing scraped data

    #Counters for keeping track:
    total_scraped = 0 
    total_invalid = 0
    errors = 0


    for postal_code in range(1001,5000):

        #This if statement is necessary because the postal code can't start 
        #with 0 in order for the for statement to interate successfully
        if postal_code <10000:
            postal_code_string = str(0)+str(postal_code) 
        else:
            postal_code_string = str(postal_code) 

        #all postal code URLs have the same format on this site
        url = 'http://www.city-data.com/zips/' + postal_code_string + '.html'

        #try to get current URL 
        try: 
            response = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
            http = response.status_code

            #print current for logging purposes
            print url +" - HTTP:  " + str(http)

            #if valid webpage:
            if http == 200:

                #save html as text
                html = response.text

                #extra print statement for status updates
                print "HTML ready"

                #try to find two substrings in HTML text
                #add the substring in between them to list w/ postal code
                try:            

                    found = re.search('population in 2011:</b> (.*)<br>', html).group(1)

                    #add to # scraped counter
                    total_scraped +=1

                    postal_code_data.append([postal_code_string,found])

                    #print statement for logging
                    print postal_code_string + ": " + str(found) + ". Data scrape successful. " + str(total_scraped) + " total zips scraped."
                #if substrings not found, try searching for others
                #and doing the same as above    
                except AttributeError:
                    found = re.search('population in 2010:</b> (.*)<br>', html).group(1)

                    total_scraped +=1

                    postal_code_data.append([postal_code_string,found])
                    print postal_code_string + ": " + str(found) + ". Data scrape successful. " + str(total_scraped) + " total zips scraped."

            #if http =404, zip is not valid. Add to counter and print log         
            elif http == 404: 
                total_invalid +=1

                print postal_code_string + ": Not a valid zip code. " + str(total_invalid) + " total invalid zips."

            #other http codes: add to error counter and print log
            else:
                errors +=1

                print postal_code_string + ": HTTP Code Error. " + str(errors) + " total errors."

        #if get url fails by connnection error, add to error count & pass
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            errors +=1
            print postal_code_string + ": Connection Error. " + str(errors) + " total errors."
            pass

        #if get url fails by timeout error, add to error count & pass
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            errors +=1
            print postal_code_string + ": Timeout Error. " + str(errors) + " total errors."
            pass


    #print final log/counter data, along with timestamp finished
    now= datetime.datetime.now() 
    print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    print str(total_scraped) + " total zips scraped." 
    print str(total_invalid) + " total unavailable zips."
    print str(errors) + " total errors."
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to scrape those. Have you looked at the U.S. Census Bureau's [data](https://www.census.gov/epcd/www/zipstats.html)?

Comment: You could run the script from several proxies and sleep for a while between requests.

Comment: @vch the US census bureau's data is not easily attainable, and not very accurate (this was my first idea). city-data.com's data is easier to access and more accurate.

Comment: @solarc  I've never a script from proxies before, or written one to sleep between requests. Would you be able to offer a code answer to this?

Comment: @TylerPalmer `import time; time.sleep(5)` will sleep for 5 seconds. You can add it to your loop (maybe call it once every 100 loops) and play with the time to try to get their server to reset the pageview limit.